# up/down voting system doesn't work when i add it to my html document

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using this up/down voting script. It doesn't work when i add it to my html. Thumbs show, but when i click there are no changes to database entries so i guess something is wrong at database; maybe i have 2 connections because i already selected from mysql data to show? i have no clue. Please give me tips what should i check in those cases. Once again everything works outside my index if i use the downloaded files separately.

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/04/voting-system-with-jquery-php

I know this can be a wide problem and i am sorry for asking this but i am desperate to know what could be the solution for this.

EDIT: i have fixed previous problem, i have another problem now i.e. whenever i click any vote it stays at number 0 and it gives error as "already voted", even though i haven't.

here is line of that in php:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["voted_".$unique_content_id]))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Already Voted'); //cookie found, user has already voted
            exit(); //exit script
        }
```

Comment: if you have some scripts then please attach.

Comment: i don't klnow what to attach because everything works if i dont use it in my html..

Comment: It is your responsibility to post a minimal example which demonstrates your problem, when asking a question on this site. If your code doesn't work, keep cutting unnecessary stuff out until you find the smallest possible case that doesn't work. Then post that. This might take you a long time: unfortunately debugging a newly learned language is time-consuming and something you will need to get used to as a programmer. You'll be doing yourself a favor if you follow the rules of this site.

Comment: i know.. i only asked this because i am trying to fix this for 10+ hours

Comment: at least jQuery where the up / down vote works.

Comment: guys omg! i fixed it i didn't include js script 1.09. because i already had js script 1.11 so i thought it is improved version of it. sorry for asking guys once again thank you all

Comment: now clicking on it works, but number of likes /dislikes won't change. it stays at 0. what error could it be? mysql or php?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it i didn't include js script 1.09. because i already had js script 1.11 so i thought it is improved version of it. sorry for asking guys once again thank you al